# Pyqrt5 Calculator

Tags: python, functional-buttons

Коллеги, прошу помочь. Нужно чтобы при нажатии любой цифры, старая цифра не должна стираться на экране, то есть оставаться нужны нажатие цифры.

Пример кода:

```
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.after_clicked(num=0))
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=1))
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=2))
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=3))

def after_clicked(self, num):
    self.label_2.setText(str(num))
```

Comment: `self.label_2.setText(self.label_2.text() + str(num))`

Comment: Прошу прощение, а как 0 удалить. У меня в Label_2 '0' перед цифрами

Comment: опубликуйте ваше приложение, я посмотрю на него и поправлю что у вас не так.

Comment: `self.label_2.setText(str(num) if self.label_2.text()=="0" else self.label_2.text() + str(num))`

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def after_clicked(self, num):
    self.label_2.setNum(int(self.label_2.text() + str(num)))
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Handsome_777  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Сорри... Пишет:  Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: сижу читаю,что не так делаю)

Comment: @Handsome_777 читайте пожалуйста внимательно. Вы пробуете поставить отметку, что мой ответ полезен вам и это действительно можно будет делать когда ваша репутацию будет больше 15. Сделайте отметку о том, что ответ Правильный.